# Is it possible to call a modal using ajax?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

```
$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     data : "",
     url : '<?php echo site_url("adduser/register_user");?>',
     success :   function(data){
                    $('#error').modal('show');
              }
});
```

the codes above is my code to show a modal but it didn't work. Is it possible to show a modal using ajax?

Comment: yes its possible to call modal from ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you use Bootstrap right?
If you read the documentation there is a better way to achieve the same result:

In your main file:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo site_url('adduser/register_user');?>" data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

And then in the remote file:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will show the default modal. More information in the manual: [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)